# Tomtom historical data for specific day and time

Tags: traffic

Hi I’m trying to obtain a historic visual traffic report for the B219, Peckham Rye (London, UK) on the 27/4/21 at 16.45. The request is for a court case that I am involved in due to a Road traffic accident. I understand Tomtom can provide this data, but cannot find anyone who can do such a report. Prepared to pay someone if possible.

Answer (score 0):

The [TomTom MOVE portal](https://move.tomtom.com/) should have this information. Given that you want only one location at one time, this should even be possible with the free tier.